# How to stop VS Code opening .md files in the browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, readme

I'm on Mac M2. Like the title says, every time I do open a markdown file in VS Code, it opens up in Chrome as well (in preview mode). When it does it also brings it to the top and it's annoying closing it each time. I don't want it to do it, also because VSC already has a function to show the preview of .md files so it's useless opening a Chrome tab.

I searched online but found nothing, and also could not seem to find any related setting inside VS Code.

Comment: I'd try disabling all extensions and see which one causes that... have never heard of this before...

Comment: @mb21 lol it really was that simple.. it was an extension called Instant Markdown that I had installed cause in a ext package.. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the [`dbankier.vscode-instant-markdown`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-instant-markdown) extension.

In general, if you're experiencing weird behaviour, you can check if it's caused by an extension by doing the following: Does it happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.